# Why does my site cert become insecure after a JQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a website that uses JQuery to grab information from an API located at: https://api.lootbox.eu/. The website I'm making has a cert that's been created and installed with Let's Encrypts tools. (I followed a tutorial on DigitalOcean to set it up)

Now, when I click a button to make the API call and update the website contents, Google Chrome then deems the cert "Not Secure" (shown in the address bar).

Here's my code.

```
//when the page has fully loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
function parseResponse(data)
{
    //parsing JSON...
    //lets avoid the "data.data"
    response = data.data;

    //set the user's general profile details
    $("#user_avatar").attr("src", response.avatar);
    $("#comp_rank_img").attr("src", response.competitive.rank_img);
    $("#comp_rank").html(response.competitive.rank);
    $("#qp_level").html(response.level);

    $("#qp_playtime").html(response.playtime.quick);
    $("#comp_playtime").html(response.playtime.competitive);
    $("#qp_wins").html(response.games.quick.wins);

    $("#comp_total_games").html(response.games.competitive.played);
    $("#comp_wins").html(response.games.competitive.wins);
    $("#comp_losses").html(response.games.competitive.lost);
}
//goes to the Overwatch API and grabs the JSON data for processing.
function processAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.lootbox.eu/pc/us/JuicyBidet-1292/profile"
    }).then( function(response){
        parseResponse(response);
    });
}
//set up the button event listener
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    //prevent the button from reloading the page
    e.preventDefault();
    //run the ajax grabber/processor
    processAjax();
});
});
```

(I need to learn how to format code properly in SO questions...).

I don't get any other errors in my Chrome console (other than "favicon" 404ing - which is unrelated).

I've also tried the website in Microsoft Edge and I get the following in their Console:
`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.`

I'm thinking either the problem is with my code, or now that I've checked, the API website's cert is invalid in both Chrome and Edge.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

(I'm aware the code is scrappy, I'm learning)

Comment: can you attach an image of the error shown by chrome?

Comment: as [this](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/lets-encrypt-certificates-do-not-work-on-xp-in-ie8-or-chrome/2654) link says , it's the server config that determines whether browser will accept cert or not, worth checking

Comment: I visited [https://api.lootbox.eu](https://api.lootbox.eu), the certificate for [https://api.lootbox.eu](https://api.lootbox.eu) has been expired, please renew the certificate and try again.

Comment: @jagb - it's not my website, their twitter mentions they're working on renewing it.

Comment: @Pilapodapostache I guess you'll have to wait until they renew it unless you're sure the error cause is your cert

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal there's only one error in chrome, but it's a favicon 404 error, so I don't think it's related, as I don't have a favicon set up on the server

Comment: @niceman A certificate tester that I've tried the domain on marks it as "A" and only OLD browsers have a problem with it.

Seems I can't link the results without the tests running again, but here's the link if you want to check yourself: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=frostpeak.net

Comment: It's because [https://api.lootbox.eu/](https://api.lootbox.eu/)'s certificate expired at February, 27th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get this warning "This server could not prove that it is api.lootbox.eu; its security certificate expired 6 days ago"
This could happen because of one among following reasons.

1.Certificate is not issued by the third party site.

2.The third party site certificate is not updated.

3.The third party and browser connection is not secure.

Comment: Alright. I'm relatively inexperienced with certs. I wasn't aware that if lootbox.eu wasn't secure, my website all of a sudden would be insecure if I made calls to their API. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @CaptainMagikarp You can check it. A quick look at the trust chain shows that the certificate is really from Let's Encrypt, so the first one is not valid. If you look at the certificate expire date (February 27th), the second option is true. The third is always true when your browser shows the "Invalid certificate" page.

Comment: @DineiRockenbach Thank you! Now I know at least a little bit more about certs than I did before :)

Answer (score 3):

The insecure error is because if a site is loaded over https the browser expects all subsequent calls made by the page will be secure, but in your case you are calling a URL **http://api.lootbox.eu/pc/us/JuicyBidet-1292/profile** which uses http:// and is insecure thus making your website insecure.

**Solution**

Use https url's everywhere in your pages.

Comment: My mistake, that was me messing around with my local copy. The link is https in the uploaded copy of the code. Editing the original question to reflect the change